# Regex - filter websites and IPs

Tags: regex

What regex can detect the presence of any IP address or URL in a string. It should be able to detect people trying to obviously avoid the filter: Examples:

154.43.45.345

website.com

website . com

website dot com

website?@#[]?.,<>.com

etc

Thanks!

Comment: Is this for some comment review/spam detection system? Anyway, I believe that you need set of regular expressions for different types of unwanted content, like for IP etc

Answer (score 1):

The IP Regex is very straightforward, as it's structure is constant

`(\d{1,4}\.){3}\d{1,4}`

For websites, I would need more detailed info, but the general idea is like

`.+((\.|dot).+)*(\.|dot)\s*(com|net|org|gov|uk...)`

or, extremely basic

`.*(\.|dot).*(com|net|org|gov|uk...)`

Comment: It's worth noting that (assuming case insensitivity) the sentence "Kim Dotcom was born in Germany" will contain a match for your final regex.  That may be OK for the OP's purpose, but false positives should be mentioned (and given what he's trying to do, I think they'll be pretty close to unavoidable).

Comment: @IanMcLaird You are right. I would probably need more information like is `website dot x com` valid? If not, `\s*` instead of `.*` would suffice and could add in `$` at the end of the domain.